# Lightning datatable record shows url of related record

Tags: lightning, url, lightning-datatable

I need to create an activity table like standard look and feel. I got stuck at two point

1.whoid/contact name isn't coming as per need

2. I need to create dummy checkbox field for event

**Component:**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes"
            access="global"
            controller="TaskController">
<aura:attribute name="data" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="columns" type="List"/>
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String"/>
 <aura:attribute name="finalUrl" type="String"/>
<!-- This attribute will hold the update records from data table-->
<aura:attribute name="updatedRecord" type="Object[]" />

<aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}"/>

<!-- You must define keyField as 'Id' to save the record back in Salesforce
'onsave' attribute will executed when user clicks on save button -->
<lightning:card title="Task Editable Datatable">
    <lightning:datatable
                         aura:id="taskDataTable"
                         columns="{! v.columns }"
                         data="{! v.data }"
                         keyField="Id"
                         onsave ="{!c.onSave}"
                         hideCheckboxColumn="true"
                         onrowaction="{! c.handleRowAction }" />
    </lightning:card>
</aura:component>
```

**Controller:**

```
({
    /*
     * This finction defined column header
     * and calls getAccounts helper method for column data
     * editable:'true' will make the column editable
     * */
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {     

        var actions = [
            { label: 'Edit', name: 'edit' },
            { label: 'Delete', name: 'delete' }
        ]; 
        component.set('v.columns', [
            {label: 'Subject', fieldName: 'linkName', type: 'url',
             typeAttributes: {label: { fieldName: 'Subject' }, target: '_blank'}},
            {label: 'NAME', fieldName: 'WhoId', type: 'url',
            typeAttributes: {label: { fieldName: 'WhoId' }, target: '_blank'}},
            {label: 'TASK', fieldName: 'TASK', type: 'boolean'},
            {label: 'DUE DATE', fieldName: 'ActivityDate', type: 'date'},
            {type: 'action', typeAttributes: { rowActions: actions }},
        ]);        
            helper.getTasks(component, helper);
            },

            handleRowAction: function (component, event, helper) {
            var action = event.getParam('action');
            var row = event.getParam('row');
            switch (action.name) {
            case 'edit':
            var rows = component.get('v.data');
            var rowIndex = rows.indexOf(row);
            var Taskid = rows[rowIndex].Id;
                      var action = component.get("c.TaskUrl");
        action.setParams({ recID : Taskid });
        action.setCallback(this,function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                component.set("v.finalUrl", response.getReturnValue());

                var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
                urlEvent.setParams({
                    "url": component.get("v.finalUrl")
                });
                urlEvent.fire();
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
        // var url = component.get("v.finalUrl");     
        // alert(component.get("v.finalUrl"));

        //window.open(component.get("v.finalUrl"));
        break;

        case 'delete':
        var rows = component.get('v.data');
        var rowIndex = rows.indexOf(row);
        var deleteAct = component.get("c.deleteTask");
        var Taskid = rows[rowIndex].Id;
        deleteAct.setParams({ ids : Taskid });
        $A.enqueueAction(deleteAct);
        var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
        toastEvent.setParams({
            "title": "Success!",
            "message": "The record has been delete successfully."
        });
        toastEvent.fire();
        rows.splice(rowIndex, 1);
        component.set('v.data', rows);
        break;
    }
},
 /*
     * This function is calling saveDataTable helper function
     * to save modified records
     * */
 onSave : function (component, event, helper) {
    helper.saveDataTable(component, event, helper);
}
})


({
    getTasks : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.getTasks");
        action.setCallback(this,function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                var records =response.getReturnValue();
                records.forEach(function(record){
                    record.linkName = '/'+record.Id;
                });
                component.set("v.data", records);
                //component.set("v.data", response.getReturnValue());
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },

    /*
     * This function get called when user clicks on Save button
     * user can get all modified records
     * and pass them back to server side controller
     * */
    saveDataTable : function(component, event, helper) {
        var editedRecords =  component.find("taskDataTable").get("v.draftValues");
        var totalRecordEdited = editedRecords.length;
        var action = component.get("c.updateTasks");
        action.setParams({
            'editedTaskList' : editedRecords
        });
        action.setCallback(this,function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                //if update is successful
                if(response.getReturnValue() === true){
                    helper.showToast({
                        "title": "Record Update",
                        "type": "success",
                        "message": totalRecordEdited+" Task Records Updated"
                    });
                    helper.reloadDataTable();
                } else{ //if update got failed
                    helper.showToast({
                        "title": "Error!!",
                        "type": "error",
                        "message": "Error in update"
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },


    /*
     * Show toast with provided params
     * */
    showToast : function(params){
        var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
        if(toastEvent){
            toastEvent.setParams(params);
            toastEvent.fire();
        } else{
            alert(params.message);
        }
    },

    /*
     * reload data table
     * */
    reloadDataTable : function(){
    var refreshEvent = $A.get("e.force:refreshView");
        if(refreshEvent){
            refreshEvent.fire();
        }
    },
})
```

[image: desired look]

[image: current look]

Comment: Can you post your TaskController class?  Also, can you describe your need for a dummy checkbox for the event?  Are you looking to add a checkbox to each row of the datatable, or is it something else?

Comment: @ShaneSteinfeld Some of his code was hidden because of formatting which I've fixed with an edit.

Comment: @Sankhadeep, I'd still like to see what's happening in the TaskController Apex class.  Also, I'm wondering whether Shared Activities is enabled in your org.  Try adding EventWhoIds to your query and see whether it returns a value.

Answer (score 1):

While you may have more than one issue - depending on exactly how you're querying these records in your Apex controller - one issue that I see here has to do with your column definitions.

```
    component.set('v.columns', [
        {label: 'Subject', fieldName: 'linkName', type: 'url',
         typeAttributes: {label: { fieldName: 'Subject' }, target: '_blank'}},
        {label: 'NAME', fieldName: 'WhoId', type: 'url',
        typeAttributes: {label: { fieldName: 'WhoId' }, target: '_blank'}},
    ...
    ]);
```

Here, you're correctly using a synthetic attribute `linkName` to construct a URL and a display text entry for the task itself:

```
        {label: 'Subject', fieldName: 'linkName', type: 'url',
         typeAttributes: {label: { fieldName: 'Subject' }, target: '_blank'}},
```

having previously done

```
            records.forEach(function(record){
                record.linkName = '/'+record.Id;
            });
```

but you don't do the same steps for your `WhoId`:

```
        {label: 'NAME', fieldName: 'WhoId', type: 'url',
        typeAttributes: {label: { fieldName: 'WhoId' }, target: '_blank'}},
```

If you want this column to be a link to the related record whose display is the name of the Contact or Lead, you'd need to construct that link in the same way you do with your Subject field, and you'd need to ensure that your Apex controller queries the Name field of the related object.

Because `WhoId` is polymorphic, cross-object queries are messier than usual. I believe, however, that you can get there by querying `Who.Name` in this instance, as that field's available through the `Who` relationship, and then making that field available to your Lightning data table through another synthetic property (say `whoLinkName`).